# Best way to convert a 59.94fps video to 29.97?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am tryiing to normalize the clips from multiple cameras for an amateur movie.
Thinking that 29.97 fps is the best choice for my case but my camcorder only supports recording at 59.94fps or 24fps.

What is the best way to halve the framerate down to 29.97fps, perhaps skipping every other frame?
I usually use ffmpeg for transcoding but I couldn't find much resource on changing the actual framerate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, dropping every other frame and re-encoding is what you need, `ffmpeg -r ntsc` should do the trick.

This is a quick-and-dirty framerate conversion, if you wanted to lose as little information as possible you'd have to create motion blur from combined frames using some filter, probably not integrated in ffmpeg though. This would more accurately simulate the camera recording at a lower framerate.

Comment: Use `-r ntsc` or `-r 30000/1001`, not `-r 29.97`.

Comment: @llogan Why `-r 30000/1001` instead of the "easier" 29.97?

Comment: @Fusseldieb Because "29.97" is a lazy, less exact alias for the NTSC standard which is actually 30000/1001 (29.97002997 repeating). The small difference won't matter for most users and internet videos, but it will if need to sync various NTSC sources, encode for broadcast, or have to deal with timecode then it can be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure how you wanted to convert the video, but using Handbrake, I am able to convert a video at 59.94FPS to 29.97FPS. In the video options there is a setting for framerate (default set to "same as source") that can be set to a wide range of values including 29.97FPS.